# Deleting first N prime numbers from a list (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, primes

Basically I want to remove the first `N` numbers from a list, the function that checks whether a number is prime or not seems to work well but the program itself doesn't

For example for input `[2,4,5,7,6,9,11]` and `N = 3` I should get `[4, 6, 9, 11]` but I get only `[4, 6, 9]`.

```
divisible(X,Y) :- 
    0 is X mod Y, !.
divisible(X,Y) :- 
    X > Y+1, 
    divisible(X, Y+1).

%isPrime function check whether or not the argument is a prime number
isPrime(2) :- true,!.
isPrime(X) :- X < 2,!,false.
isPrime(X) :- not(divisible(X, 2)).

%delFunction (input_list, N, output_list)
delFunction([],_,_).
delFunction(_,0,_).
delFunction([H|T], N, [H|Res]):-
    not(isPrime(H)), !,
    delFunction(T, N, Res).
delFunction([_|T], N, Res):-
    N1 is N-1,
    delFunction(T,N1,Res).
```

`delFunction([2,4,5,7,6,9,11],3,X)` -> `[4,6,9]` (which is not the correct answer)

Honestly, I don't know where I went wrong, the implementation idea seems pretty easy and straight forward, so is the code.

Also, when I run it it stops at `[4]` and I have to keep on clicking next to get me to the end of the execution (thus the result). Any idea how to fix it? I'm thinking maybe I need some cuts but not sure where.

P.S: I'd rather not use built-in functions (if there are any that would help in this scenario)

Comment: Yea, well, those are my problems. Final output isn't correct and it gives me multiple answers (when it should give only one, obviously). Still think it's a misuse of ! somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Fists of all, instead of

```
delFunction([],_,_).
```

you should write

```
delFunction([],_,[]).
```

because when the input list (the left one) is empty, you have to construct the base for the output list: an empty list; with `delFunction([], _, _)` you don't unify the output list with the empty list so the result end with an not unified variable.

Second. Instead of

```
delFunction(_,0,_).
```

you should write

```
delFunction(L,0,L).
```

The problem is the same: when number is zero you can "copy" the input in the output; that is, you can unify they; that is `delFunction(L,0,L)`. With `delFunction(_,0,_)` you don't unify and the result ends with a not unified variable.

Third. In the is-prime clause

```
delFunction([_|T], N, Res):-
    N1 is N-1,
    delFunction(T,N1,Res).
```

you should check that `N` is greater than zero

```
delFunction([_|T], N, Res):-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    delFunction(T,N1,Res).
```

or, if you prefer, you should add a cut (`!`) in the zero clause

```
delFunction(L,0,L) :- !.
```

Just to avoid that Prolog, via backtracking, can give multiple undesired answers.

**--- EDIT ---**

As Guy Coder, I avoid cuts like a plague; so I propose the following solution to avoid unwanted repetitions.

```
delFunction([], _, []).

delFunction([H | T], 0, [H | T]).

delFunction([H | T], N, [H | Res]) :-
    N > 0,
    not(isPrime(H)),
    delFunction(T, N, Res).

delFunction([H | T], N, Res):-
    N > 0,
    isPrime(H),
    N1 is N-1,
    delFunction(T, N1, Res).
```

Comment: @GuyCoder - with wich call? With `delFunction([2,4,5,7,6,9,11],3,X)`?

Comment: Thanks man, Really helped out, it works now and gives only 1 answer.

Comment: @GuiCoder - with swi-prolog I get only one answer but with gprolog I get 3. There is to add the `N > 0` che before `not(isPrime())`

Comment: @GuyCoder, Hansewl - modified my answer; hope it's clearer.